How can I solve it so that a banned USB user is not banned on a specific computer?
I have 2 group policies, USB_Disable (all authenticated users are included here) and one USB_Enabled (which contains a group of users). My goal would be that there are machines on which USB must be enabled. How can I solve this?
I created a group in which I put the machines.

I put it in the USB_Disable GPO and set it in its properties so that it cannot read or run.
I put it in the USB_Enable GPO
I made a separate policy, but USB Disable has a higher order

None of my attempts were successful. There is a solution
Thanks
johny989

If you have prepared your Group Policy objects that block USB drives in User Configuration section,then

Create a GPO that contains "Configure User Loopback Policy Processing" enabled in "Merge" Mode (This setting is in Computer Configuration). Add USB enabling settings to this GPO in User Configuration
part. Modify the security filtering on this GPO to Read and Apply it to only specific computers and the users that will use USB drives on those computers.

Move departmental specific computers that you want to enable USB drives for limited users to a subOU under department OU and link the GPO that you have created above to this subOU.

So when the specific user logs on to the domain from those specific PCs, they will apply the user settings part of the group policy objects applied to those specific computers. Since the user settings will contain the setting that will enable USB drives, besides other user settings inherited from the user's OU ; USB enable setting will apply to that user. Other normal users will not see USB drives even they logon to domain from specific computers because security filtering will not allow them  to apply Loopback&USB Enabling policy on those specific computers

All users will see their profiles/settings on specific computers since Loopback Group Policy Processing is in Merge Mode.


For the details you may check:
Ref: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/back-to-the-loopback-troubleshooting-group-policy-loopback/ba-p/400218
